# cProfile.run() isn't doing anything

Tags: python

This is probably a stupid question but I've spent 2 hours researching this problem and seem to be the only person with it.

```
import cProfile
cProfile.run('import game; game.main()')
```

All this does is run and return the game.main() function.  The result is no different than running game.main() without cProfile.  But everyone else on the internet seems to get a nice, neat table of data from the virtually identical code.  What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Do you see the same problem with other statements in the `.run()` method? For example, try `cProfile.run('print("foo")')`. Does that work?

Comment: Does `game.main()` terminate? Or is it an interactive game with an infinite loop that you have to stop with `Ctrl+C`?

Comment: @senshin, cProfile.run('print("foo")') does work.  I get a table of info.

Comment: @Bakuriu, it is an infinite loop.  Ah, I see.  I didn't think to stop it with Ctrl+C.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cProfile.run` does produce a table with profiling statistics *when the code snippet ends*.
In your case the call to `game.main()` is an infinite loop, so `cProfile` will simply run the loop until it stops for some reason.

You can try to break out of an infinite loop by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> which will raise a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception in the program.
When the program exits you'll see the table of the statistics (and also the traceback of the exception).